# C++ "Expected a ';' Error when creating 2 functions close to eachother

Tags: c++

So, I am creating my first decent sized game using functions with just cmd, because I'm bad at coding and started not too long ago. I was doing some work with functions and I came across an annoying error that I cannot seem to fix.

It is a Battle royal simulation like game, and the function is to find the weapon they start with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include "Players.h"

using namespace std;
string Itemgrab1_1();
int Chance();

vector<int> Percentiles;

int main() {
string Firstitem = "None";
int PeC = 0;
Player1 Player1;
Player2 Player2;
default_random_engine Chancegen(time(NULL));
uniform_int_distribution<int> Pec(1, 100);

//Gives Player 1 his first item
if (Firstitem == "Bow") {
    cout << "He also grabs 5 Arrows.\n";
    Player1.itembow = 1;
    Player1.arrows = 5;
}
if (Firstitem == "Sword") {
    Player1.itemsword = 1;
}
if (Firstitem == "Knife") {
    Player1.itemknife = 1;
}
if (Firstitem == "Axe") {
    Player1.itemaxe = 1;
}

// Decides the first item for the players
string Itemgrab1_1() { //Error is RIGHT here
    default_random_engine Itemgen(time(NULL));
    uniform_int_distribution<int> FirstItem(1, 4);
    int FirstItemP1 = FirstItem(Itemgen);
    if (FirstItemP1 == 1) {
        return "Sword";
    }
    if (FirstItemP1 == 2) {
        return "Knife";
    }
    if (FirstItemP1 == 3) {
        return "Axe";
    }
    if (FirstItemP1 == 4) {
        return "Bow";
    }
}
```

The game depends hevily on this function, it is called early on and it worked for a little while, until I tried to add another function for Random Chance.

```
   int Chance() {
default_random_engine Chancegen(time(NULL));
uniform_int_distribution<int> Pec(1, 100);
int percentchance = Pec(Chancegen);
Percentiles.push_back(percentchance); //logging with a vector because I'm curious

return percentchance;
}
```

As soon as I put it in and fixed any errors I made, the first function stopped working. I did do a bit of testing and switched the orders of the two, when I did that I got the same error, but on the Chance function.

There are no other errors in this project. It is expecting a ;

A couple of classes in another file.
    #pragma once
    #include 
    #include

```
using namespace std;

class Player1
{
public:
    Player1();
    bool AtkR = false;
    int HP = 2;
    int POS = 0;
    int itemsword = 0;
    int itemknife = 0;
    int itemaxe = 0;
    int itembow = 0;
    int arrows = 0;

private:
    string _name = "Player 1";
};

class Player2
{
public:
    Player2();
    bool AtkR = false;
    int HP = 2;
    int POS = 0;
    int itemsword = 0;
    int itemknife = 0;
    int itemaxe = 0;
    int itembow = 0;
    int arrows = 0;

private:
    string _name = "Player 2";
};
```

I would include my entire int main(); but it's such a mess that I dont think it'd be any help

I found what happened, my int main() was missing it's closing brace for some reason. Everything is working perfectly now.

Comment: A little bit below what I grabbed from my project. It is there, I just had to check.

Comment: @Supercowboy12 Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Also, what is the exact error?

Comment: OT: if your `Itemgrab1_1` would compile - it would exhibit undefined behavior due to not returning on all execution paths.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius It's impossible for the function not to return a value.

Comment: Your `main` function is missing a closing brace, also while "//Error is RIGHT here" is probably true from the compiler's point of view, it's not necessarily where you should be looking.

Comment: @George As explained in section 9.6.3.2 of C++17 standard, "_Flowing off the end of a constructor, a destructor, or a function with a cv `void` `return` type is equivalent to a `return` with no operand. Otherwise, flowing off the end of a function other than `main` results in undefined behavior_". So, yes, it's possible to not `return` anything, and compilers are not required to issue a diagnostic, and such an act, makes the function exhibit undefined behavior. However, any decent compiler would issue a warning, provided if warning level is high enough.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius "So, yes, it's possible to not return anything" How? My understanding of that quote is that ub is only invoked once the control scope of a function with a non `void` return type is left without returning anything .  And as far as I can tell `FirstItemP1` will always be `1`,`2`,`3` pr `4`. Though the function is not very clear, if the function must return a `string` I think something like `string items[] = {"fes","asd"}; return items[FirstItemP1];` would be preferable.

Comment: @George I am sorry, how did you came to the conclusion, that "_`FirstItemP1` will always be `1`,`2`,`3` or `4`_"? There's no declaration of `FirstItem` function. How can you know that it, whatever it is, would never return anything beyond those four values?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius `FirstItem` is not a function but a (presumably standard) `uniform_int_distribution<int>` , that overloads `operator()`.

Comment: @George I could swear that I tried searching for `FirstItem`, and I didn't found anything beyond the `std::string` in the `main`.. Now, I can see what you mean. When I don't see `return` on all of code-paths I always assume UB :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten the closing brace for your `main` function.

Note that better indentation might help you avoid this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int main() {
string Firstitem = "None";
int PeC = 0;
Player1 Player1;
Player2 Player2;
default_random_engine Chancegen(time(NULL));
uniform_int_distribution<int> Pec(1, 100);

//Gives Player 1 his first item
if (Firstitem == "Bow") {
    cout << "He also grabs 5 Arrows.\n";
    Player1.itembow = 1;
    Player1.arrows = 5;
}
if (Firstitem == "Sword") {
    Player1.itemsword = 1;
}
if (Firstitem == "Knife") {
    Player1.itemknife = 1;
}
if (Firstitem == "Axe") {
    Player1.itemaxe = 1;
}
} //This right here
```